# Структура Базы данных для "Прокат комп. игр"

Tags: mysql, база-данных, jdbc

Здравствуйте, буду писать приложение с подключением БД. Тема Бд: "прокат комп. игр". Так вот я не могу толком составить в голове структуру. Вот например 1 таблица - я решил что будет продавцы (пусть там будет поля: фамилия, адрес и дата проката), 2 таблица - фильмы (поля : жанр , цена и например краткое описание) нужно еще бы сделать 3 таблицу  - я думал сделать таблицу клиенты но как бы потом связать эти 3 таблицы логически? Я вот думал объединить таблицы фильмы с продавцом, но тогда что получается что каждому продавцу будет соответствовать каждый фильм? Это глупо, ну правда можно например сделать так чтобы одному продавцу соответствовало несколько фильмов ( связь один ко многим) , но тогда будет куча повторяющихся фамилий в таблице. Прошу вас помочь мне составить общую схему чтобы представлять что мне делать. Спасибо!

Comment: А у вас один и тот же фильм не может продавать несколько продавцов. Мне почему то видится связь многие ко многим. Если у вас связь все таки один(продавец) ко многим(фильмам), то в таблице фильмы добавляете ID продавца. А если многие ко многим - то отдельная таблица с двумя полями ID-продавца ID-фильма

Comment: @Mike а смотрите если например. Есть продавец Иванов  - ему будет соответствовать фильмы Чужой, Джеймс Бонд, Трансформеры. Так вот если сделать связь один ко многим то выходит что фамилия повториться несколько раз в таблице? Это допустимо? Или в таком случае как то группируется или как ?

Comment: Вы не поняли, у вас две таблицы, в продавцах помимо ФИО лежит ID этого продавца, которое первичный ключ. В таблице фильмов кроме полей которые положены фильму у вас есть поле ID-продавца. Вот продает ваш Иванов с ID=1 несколько фильмов. В продавцах запись одна, в фильмах есть сто фильмов у каждого из которых в поле Id-продавца стоит 1.

Comment: @Mike да да я это и имел в виду , смотрите  я например Иванову присвоил 3 фильма http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1464347110/ea076afe/12808561.png
 ,  я спрашиваю про сам вывод это нормально что фамилия будет вот так повторяться 3 раза или лучше выводить по другим полям?  просто у меня еще стоит задача нормализации  вот и спрашиваю, извините что надоедаю

Comment: Ну нормализация в базе, а на выводе разворачиваете в то, как это должно выглядеть. Если вам нужен просто список всех фильмов, то там все ясно, фильмы и фамилии рядом. Если нужны фильмы по конкретному продавцу так и пишете в заголовке "Фильмы Иванова" и список названий. Хотите рядом с фамилией пишите их просто через запятую, собрав на клиенте в такой список или с помощью какой нибудь group_concat

Comment: @Mike вы знаете а вы правы , тут связь же должна быть многие ко многим, я же не могу вот 3 фильма привязать именно к одному Иванову, эти же фильмы потом возвращаются и могут быть отданы от другой фамилии, скажем вот я привяжу "Трансформеры" Иванову, а если те же Трансформеры отдает Петров...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таблица 1. **Продавцы** 
[Id, FIO, ...]

Таблица 2. **Клиенты**
[Id, FIO, ...]

Таблица 3. **Диски** (игры, фильмы)
[Id, Title, ..., Status]

Таблица 4. **Аренда** (ведь диски даются на прокат)
[Id, StartArendaDate, EndArendaDate, Id_Disk, Id_Client, Id_Customer]

Примерно так.

Comment: В таблицу `Аренда` было бы еще полезно добавить поле с датой фактического возврата диска, чтобы можно было, например, выяснить, какие клиенты забывают вернуть диски вовремя. Ну и вообще, вся эта аренда вряд ли делается безвоздмездно, так что надо бы хранить и какую-то финансовую информацию. :)

Comment: Да без проблем... все что необходимо. Я предложил путь решения задачи, а дальше, все что душа пожелает

Answer (score 0):

Нужна таблица "Заказ". Туда пишешь id проданных дисков, id продавца и покупателя, дату, сумму и т.п.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?